# Function to new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to send function to the new window and get result in parent window(and after that child window should be closed).
For example I have array with URL's.

```
var urls = ["first.com", "second.com", "third.com"...];
```

and function

```
function parse(url){...}
```

then I make cycle

```
for(var i=0; i<=n; i++){window.open(url[i];}
```

How can I send "parse" and get its result?

Comment: Set up a server side scraper instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample code provided, and the fact that the domains are different, I'm going to assume that you don't own all of the domains that you're trying to open...

You need to do a bit of research on cross site scripting, and the implications of this type of functionality. To get you started, here's the definition of cross site scripting, [found here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

> Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks are a type of injection, in which
>   malicious scripts are injected into otherwise benign and trusted web
>   sites. XSS attacks occur when an attacker uses a web application to
>   send malicious code, generally in the form of a browser side script,
>   to a different end user. Flaws that allow these attacks to succeed are
>   quite widespread and occur anywhere a web application uses input from
>   a user within the output it generates without validating or encoding
>   it.

**TLDR:** Simply put, if you don't own the domains, what you're trying to do is not possible client-side.

Comment: Oh, sure. Its not my domains, in fact its 1 url(but another pages). Can you help me? I need to get information from this site to do research work. And always have "parser-blocking, cross site scriptis invoked via document.write..." 
At the begining I try to make cycle with "window.location"(Its not working)
And now I try to make  cycle with "window.open". 
Are there any other ways? If you need I can add my script

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков, I *have* helped you. **What you're trying to do is not possible.** It is considered an XSS attack, and is blocked by all browsers. This is the one and only answer, and there are no work-arounds or alternatives unless you own the domain that you're trying to inject code into.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by James Hill, this does not seem to be possible. If it helps, try web scraping to extract data from websites and process these data in functions at your own site.

There is already a chrome extension for web scraping:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn